# CDIDeploymentRuntimeException in WAS 9 Inject is not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, websphere-8, websphere-9

After migrating from WAS 8 to WAS 9 we are getting the following exceptions , it Used to work in WAS 8.

Project is using : WAS 9, JSF MyFaces 2.2 , J2EE 7 , primefaces .

Caused by: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 5 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type TestClassBF with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private cm.test.TestClassBF.testMethodBF

Comment: Post the gereric pieces of the error in a search engine of your liking and add 'site:stackoverflow.com' to it

Comment: Oh and j2ee7 does not exists... java-ee 7 does

Comment: :) yes right JavaEE 7.0 and the jar name is j2ee on websphere application server

Comment: There are many questions and answers about the WELD-001408 error on this site.  Since you're going from CDI 1.0 on WAS 8.0 to CDI 1.2 on WAS 9, looking at your beans.xml and bean-discovery-mode is a good start.